# Java, Firestore - Get multiple documents from firestore using an arraylist of document ids in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an ArrayList which contains all the ids I want to fetch. Is there a way I can fetch multiple documents and their field values using the list. Also, if I have to manually create a for loop to get each document, how shall I do it?

Firestore data structure:

```
Users:
  user1:
     field1 :
     field2 :
     field3 :
     field4 :
  user2:
     field1 :
     field2 :
     field3 :
     field4 :
  user3:
     field1 :
     field2 :
     field3 :
     field4 :
```

The list contains : user1,user2,user3 and so on...

Edit 1:
I tried to get it using a for loop but it gives a null pointer exception
at `FriendsData.add(userDetails);`

```
 for (String doc : list_of_Friends) {
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(doc).get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                    FamilyMember userDetails = documentSnapshot.toObject(FamilyMember.class);
                                    FriendsData.add(userDetails);
                                }
                            });
```

Edit 2:

Another logic for the loop also gives the same error.
When I log, I can see that both the `doc` & `ds.getId()` are getting values

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()){
                                for (String doc : list_of_Friends) {
                                    if(ds.getId().equals(doc)){
                                        FriendsData.add(ds.toObject(FamilyMember.class));
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Which ways have you tried to retrieve the documents?

Comment: I tried using a for loop to add each document one by one, but it gives null pointer exception

Comment: Do all the documents have similar attributes/fields?

Comment: Yes, they have equal number of fields.

Comment: I have updated the changes i have made to the loop. Pls check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are calling `.get()` on a DocumentReference object, you are getting back a `Task<DocumentSnapshot>` object.

> Is there a way I can fetch multiple documents and their field values using the list.

Yes, it is. The key to solving this problem is [`whenAllSuccess(Collection<? extends Task<?>> tasks)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) method. In your particular case, the code should look like this:

```
List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (String doc : list_of_Friends) {
    tasks.add(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(doc).get());
}

Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
        //Do what you need to do with your list
        for (Object object : list) {
            FamilyMember fm = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(FamilyMember.class);
            Log.d("TAG", fm.getName());
        }
    }
});
```

Assuming that you have in your `FamilyMember` class a property called `name` and a getter called `getName()`, the result in your logcat will be all the names of all family members.

Comment: Didn't expect to get an answer from you. Big pleasure. Your answers have helped me a lot earlier as well.