# How to Fetch Collections based on another collections field value inside the loop in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In our app we are trying to fetch all the products and by iterating each product trying to get `specificationId` which is equal to another `documentId` in seperate collection Specifications.

Basically the structure is like below:

**ProductDetail**

- productId
- productTitle
- productDescription
- specificationId

**Specification**

- documentId — this is autogenerated id for collection which is being used as `specificationId` in `ProductDetail` collection.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Query productResponseQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("productdetails")
            .limit(50);

    productResponseQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

            if (error != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: " + error.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            querySnapshot.forEach(doc -> {
                ProductDetailResponse productDetailResponse = new ProductDetailResponse();
                productDetailResponse.setProductImage(doc.getData().get("productImageUrl").toString());
                productDetailResponse.setProductTitle(doc.getData().get("productTitle").toString());
                productDetailResponse.setProductShortDesc(doc.getData().get("productShortDesc").toString());
                productDetailResponse.setProductDesc(doc.getData().get("productDescription").toString());

               populateSpecification(doc.getData().get("specId").toString());

            });
        }
    });

 private void populateSpecification(String specId){
    DocumentReference specDocumentRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("specifications")
            .document(specId);

    specDocumentRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.getResult().exists()){
                task.getResult();
            }else{
                task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I understand that the Firestore database calls are asynchronous in nature. Hence if I call the specificationQuery inside the for loop, without waiting for the result it is jumping to the next iteration.

Is there any way without changing the structure I can achieve the result, which will basically show all the product details along with their respective specification collection?

Comment: It sounds like you want to wait for all those tasks to complete. I recommend checking out the [Become a Firebase Taskmaster](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1) blog series, specifically [part 4](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4) which covers `Tasks.whenAll`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Firestore: How to acess a collection from another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145265/firebase-firestore-how-to-acess-a-collection-from-another-collection)

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698816/java-firestore-get-multiple-documents-from-firestore-using-an-arraylist-of-do/) will also help.